# HttpWebRequest unhandled "invalidcastexception" casting HttpWebResponse to System.Exception

Tags: c#, exception, casting, httpwebrequest

we have an application that makes calls to a remote web address using the HttpWebRequest class, which we get through the `WebRequest.Create` method.

This is our actual code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "HEAD";
request.Timeout = this.connectionTimeout;

if (this.usePipelinedConnection)
{
     request.KeepAlive = true;
     request.Pipelined = true;
}

request.BeginGetResponse(cb => logService.EndGetRequestStream(cb), null);
```

Now in a non-deterministic way (can't find a pattern to reproduce it) we get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException
>
> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse' to type 'System.Exception'.

with this stack trace:

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
>
> at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CaptureOrComplete(ExecutionContext& cachedContext, Boolean returnContext)
>
> at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.FinishPostingAsyncOp()
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

Documentation about this method reports several exceptions that can be thrown, but `InvalidCastException` is not one of those, meaning that it is unhandled in microsoft method.
I started digging in .Net sources, and I think I found the culprit. In the HttpWebResponse.EndGetResponseStream method, there's this line:

```
throw (Exception) lazyAsyncResult.Result;
```

That's the only cast to Exception present in this method, so that must be it. Now the method is implemented in a way that it will reach this line only if the connectionstream is null, so the `lazyasyncresult.Result` property should contain an exception. In my case however, the branch is reached but `lazyasyncresult.Result` contains an `HttpWebResponse`, thus the boxing fails and I get that error. Now I have two considerations:

- If the content of `lazyasyncresult.Result` were correct, it would throw anyway (since the line starts with a throw) but it would be a meaningful error;
- Related to previous point, I think that if I have an HttpWebResponse the code branch that throws shouldnt be reached anyway

Now my questions is plain simple: how do I prevent this from happening? I'm doing something wrong in my code or it's a plain bug in MS method?

Here follows, for reference, the MS source of the method. I added some comments on the incriminated line.

Thanks everyone for your time.

```
public Stream EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, out TransportContext context)
    {
      if (Logging.On)
        Logging.Enter(Logging.Web, (object) this, "EndGetRequestStream", "");
      context = (TransportContext) null;
      if (asyncResult == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("asyncResult");
      LazyAsyncResult lazyAsyncResult = asyncResult as LazyAsyncResult;
      if (lazyAsyncResult == null || lazyAsyncResult.AsyncObject != this)
        throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("net_io_invalidasyncresult"), "asyncResult");
      if (lazyAsyncResult.EndCalled)
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("net_io_invalidendcall", new object[1]
        {
          (object) "EndGetRequestStream"
        }));
      }
      else
      {
        ConnectStream connectStream = lazyAsyncResult.InternalWaitForCompletion() as ConnectStream;
        lazyAsyncResult.EndCalled = true;
        if (connectStream == null)
        {
          if (Logging.On)
            Logging.Exception(Logging.Web, (object) this, "EndGetRequestStream", lazyAsyncResult.Result as Exception);

// Here result contains HttpWebResponse so the cast to Exception fails. 
// It would throw anyway (since there' a throw) but I think, since result contains a response
// that the code shouldn't be hitting this if branch.
          throw (Exception) lazyAsyncResult.Result;
        }
        else
        {
          context = (TransportContext) new ConnectStreamContext(connectStream);
          if (Logging.On)
            Logging.Exit(Logging.Web, (object) this, "EndGetRequestStream", (object) connectStream);
          return (Stream) connectStream;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find the reason for this error ?

Answer (score 3):

I have not used this async task library ever, and forgive me if this is a naive question. But.. arent you calling the wrong EndGetXXX function?

`request.BeginGetResponse(cb => logService.EndGetRequestStream(cb), null);`

I dont know what that logService variable is, but shouldnt it be invoking EndGetResponse() instead?